# Facebook integration work, but not on my iPhone

Tags: objective-c

I have a little question about my Facebook integration in my App.
In my Simulator, it's all perfect, but if I am testing the app at my normal 
IPhone (5) the Facebook post window don't open. I get no error or warnings but nothing happens.

Maybe you have any ideas, thank you!

Have a nice day!

//edit: my code

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

}

Comment: you should show some code

Comment: Oh yeas, I forgot it, sry.
But I doesn't think that the misstake is in my Code, because all work in the simulator :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this check:

```
[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]
```

Here is how your code should look like:

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Apparently if you are not logged into Facebook **(Settings -> Facebook)** then it will return false on the iPhone but returns true on Simulator.